# How to add text to system clipboard with Qt while the window is hidden?

Tags: python, qt5, pyside2

I need to copy text into the system clipboard when window is hidden.
Copying works flawless as long as the window is shown, but after a `window.hide()` I can't update the clipboard. I have no idea why this is the case.

Do you have ideas how to solve this or know any workarounds I should try?

**Background:**

My actual application needs time to process data before the results can be copied into the clipboard. During this time I hide the window and have the application running in a `QSystemTrayIcon` which also shows a notification when the processing is complete. If everything worked, the result should be copied to clipboard and the application should quit. The final solution should work cross platform.

**Minimal example:**

```py
from PySide2 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore

 
class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.button_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Just Copy")
        self.button_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Hide and Copy")
        self.button_1.clicked.connect(self.copy_to_clipboard)
        self.button_2.clicked.connect(self.hide_and_copy_to_clipboard)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.button_1)
        layout.addWidget(self.button_2)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(3000)
        self.timer.start()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.show_if_hidden)         

    def copy_to_clipboard(self):
        # This works correctly
        clipboard = QtGui.QGuiApplication.clipboard()
        clipboard.setText("just copy")

    def hide_and_copy_to_clipboard(self):
        # Here the clipboard doesn't get updated!
        self.hide()
        clipboard = QtGui.QGuiApplication.clipboard()
        clipboard.setText("hide and copy")

    def show_if_hidden(self):
        if self.isHidden():
            self.show()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.quit()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)

window = Window()
window.show()

app.exec_()
```

**My setup:**

- Ubuntu 21.04, Python 3.9,  PySide2 5.15.2

Comment: Have you read the [QClipboard documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qclipboard.html#notes-for-x11-users) for X11? It clearly says that: "You should not store or retrieve the clipboard contents in response to timer or non-user-input events."

Comment: @musicamante, have you took a look at the minimal example? It demonstrates the issue exists in context of a direct user interaction (button click). The timer in the example is only used to re-show the window to be able to try again. 
Also for me "should not" doesn't mean "can't be done" and I'd be willing to compromise, too.

Comment: "Should not" means that you *can* try do to it, but it's not suggested/reliable; that section also has references related to clipboard ownership (which changes when another window gets focus). Clipboard management on X11 is not "standard": there are various programs and wm/de that interact with it in different ways and with different results, so the result is an unexpected or unreliable behavior (hence the "should not"). Your code works fine on my Linux (fluxbox with CopyQ), but maybe Ubuntu's clipboard manager ignores clipboard events that come from programs that don't have a focused window.

Comment: Thanks for trying the code on your system! Since 21.04 the default DE in Ubuntu is Wayland, which might also be part of the problem... A workaround for me is using `xclip`, which seems to be able to do the job. But as an additional system dependency I would rather avoid it, if possible.

Comment: I'd suggest you to do some further testing with some VM using different distros and environments. I know an additional dependency seems annoying, but xclip is pretty standard, common and lightweight, and you can consider using it as an optional dependency, while warning the user about the possible issue in case it's not already installed. In any case, read the [clipboard section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_selection#Clipboard) about X Window selection, which partially explains the issue, and consider that the Wayland protocol is slightly different.